# Apply changes to Database later/manually

Tags: c#, oracle, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to achieve this?

1. Download/fetch data from the database then save locally to a Windows Mobile app for later use (without internet connection).
2. Make changes to the database locally.
3. Upload the changes of the local database to update the database from the server manually.

I am thinking about a sync function but I am using an Oracle Database on the server and Oracle DB and SQL Server Compact doesn't support syncing with each other naturally.

Comment: It seems you'll have to write a syncing bridge yourself to accomplish this.

Comment: Just an idea, I encountered a similar requirement, and I end up implementing a FileSystem watcher keeping with files in an FTP server to handle databases downloaded and uploaded (as CSV) by the mobile devices. So it's indeed possible, but you'll need to create your own handler on both server and clients

Comment: I wonder why the down vote. I always find it depressing when some one tries to downvote a question without explaining why. :|

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is completely possible, but you are going to need to write the syncing feature yourself unfortunately. You might be able to incorporate [this](http://oracle-apps-dba.blogspot.com/2008/04/oracle-transparent-gateway-for-ms-sql_16.html), but as of now there is no bolt-on solution for you, so you would need to add the syncing features.

Happy coding!

Comment: Do you mean that I have to manually compare the changes between the local data and the data on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Please read about the ADO.NET technology.
It was made for implementation of your scenario - maintaining of disconnected cache of server data.

For example look at  [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners)

And here is more specific example -> [Disconnected Architecture in ADO.NET](http://www.programcall.com/3/adonet/disconnected-architecture-in-adonet.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Though I already have knowledge in connections, commands, data adapters and datasets, I am actually looking for a solution/suggestions for a scenario in which I have to download the data locally to the mobile device then upload the changes later to the DB.

Comment: ADO.NET in disconnected mode does just what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great walkthrough from Microsoft on doing exactly this:

[Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29)

Note that it was reported that this technique is not 100% reliable, meaning it can "forget" to post the latest data.

To get around this, you can add a `TimeStamp` [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) field to each table that stores the time the latest data was written or updated, then modify your queries to only pull/push the latest records.

Comment: I have come across the SQLBulkCopy Operation. I think It might get me closer to what I want to achieve. Do you think that this method:
1. Download data from server then save to local DB on app
2. Make changes to local DB data
3. When done with the user operations in the app, upload the data from local DB to the server via DataSet to Server using SQLBulkCopy

problem is my server is Oracle. and I'm not sure if there is anything like SQLBulkCopy for CF to an Oracle DB.